# Read SQS Message through .Net Core Serverless Lambda API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, serverless

I am trying to write a consumer for processing the SQS messages in AWS. I have read many articles and all of them are using a Lambda function as a consumer to read the message. Once the Lambda function is deployed, SQS trigger is added to that function. This is fine.

I am exploring the option of having .Net Core Lambda Serverless API as a consumer. I have published a customer API to get the customer details from DynamoDb using [HttpGet] action method. I am trying to use this API itself to insert/update customer data to DynamoDb. Example, If an external system posts the customer information to SQS. Then I want this Serverless API to read the message and updates to DynamoDb.

I added SQS trigger to the Serverless API but the message is not processed, I could see the SQS message moves to "Message in Flight" and getting the below exception in the Lambda.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.: NullReferenceException
   at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction.MarshallRequest(InvokeFeatures features, APIGatewayProxyRequest apiGatewayRequest, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)
   at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.AbstractAspNetCoreFunction`2.FunctionHandlerAsync(TREQUEST request, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , LambdaContextInternal )
```

My Question is,
Can Serverless API be used as a consumer for SQS or should we use only Lambda Function? Please advise.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I'm struggling with the same thing. I'm sending an Sqs message to a dotnet serverless application, but the message json is lacking details to map correctly to a controller, but I have no idea what. I was thinking of changing the LambdaEntryPoint.cs to log the incoming json of requests, so that I can workout how they map to controllers. Then I should be able to do the same thing manually in my Sqs message.

Comment: Hi @MartinLottering - no luck. I tried to use the below SQS message reading/long polling functionality in API middleware similar to how it is mentioned in the following link (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-loosely-coupled-scalable-c-applications-with-amazon-sqs-and-amazon-sns/), but did not work. Basically, create a method to manually check the SQS repeatedly instead of adding SQS trigger to Lambda function. I am thinking about other possible options.

Comment: I finally got mine working when I seperated the lambda for the sqs consumer into its own project. Now it is working great. And it is much easier to work with.

Comment: Hi @MartinLottering - Did you create lambda function as a consumer or a Serverless API? Lambda function as a consumer works as expected and very straight forward which I checked last week. Now, I am trying to consume through a serverless API.

Comment: No, I'm not using the Serverless Api as the Sqs consumer, I couldn't get it to work. I created another single lambda function project for that. It is straight forward and seems to be the recommended way of doing it, since every article and tutorial does it that way.

Comment: yes @MartinLottering, thanks for the update. I also found the same details only.